# Python gmail api: Error while establishing secure connection

Tags: python, api, gmail, google-oauth

I was trying to get my program to work with Gmail API

I followed the instructions given in the google's official tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6hQCgxgzLI  and accordingly

here is my code (which includes only authorizing):

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret.json'

store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if creds is None or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run(flow, store)
GMAIL = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

However when I run the code, the following happens

```
AttributeError: module 'oauth2client.tools' has no attribute 'run'
```

*Where did I go wrong?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample

if flags:

credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)

else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6

credentials = tools.run(flow, store)

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from tools.run() to tools.run_flow()
This mini-tutorial slash migration guide slash PSA (public service announcement) is aimed at Python developers using the Google APIs Client Library (to access Google APIs from their Python applications) currently calling oauth2client.tools.run(), and likely getting deprecation warnings and/or considering a migration to oauth2client.tools.run_flow(), its replacement.

UPDATE (Jan 2016): The run() function itself was removed from the client library in Aug 2015, so if you're using any release on or after that, any calls to run() from your application code will throw an exception. This blogpost was created for those of you in this situation and need to migrate immediately.

http://wescpy.blogspot.fr/2015/04/migrating-from-toolsrun-to-toolsrunflow.html